Can I create a composite index with a field name in URL format?
We are currently developing a large data transfer process through mongodb and spring.
I created a composite index using compass, but it is not actually used.
It seems that the field name is in Url format and is not recognized.
Is there a way to use it in this case?
I can't modify field Name.
The field Name that have issued is here.
context.extensions.http://test.kr/test/contexts/extensions/partner-id

This is a query that searches for values ​​based on the timestamp and partner-id fields.
db.massive_data.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $getField: {
              field: "http://test.kr/test/contexts/extensions/partner-id",
              input: "$context.extensions"
            }
          },
          "123231204-7088-5d5e-add6-f1241213b4a"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: "2024-06-27T00:00:00.000Z",
        $lt: "2024-06-27T23:59:59.999Z"
      }
    }
  ]
});

How can i create compose index with that 2 fields?
timestamp and context.extensions.http://test.kr/test/contexts/extensions/partner-id
With MongoCompass, I created compose index that those fields.
But, It didn't used.

Refactor your schema if possible. You are having anti-patterns of dynamic field names and storing datetime in strings instead of proper datetime object.

One of the ways you could refactor your schema is like this. You can easily build a composite index on it. For your current situation, you can consider parsing and migrating the data like this

@ray
First of all, thank you for your reply. However, because the model was designed by an external customer, it is difficult to modify. Is there no way in the current situation?

please refer to the second playground that I have provided for the migration.

You cannot - redesign your database. The next failure seems to be the timestamp field. Never store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Use proper Date objects. This schema has bad performance by design.

According to the Documentataion, no field names that contain dot(.) or dollar sign($) cannot be indexed.
